# JSR 330 javax.inject.Provider didn't inject org.springframework.core.env.Environment in @Autowired field

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jsr, jsr330

I was using Provider to create prototype beans(with @Autowired fields) in a for loop

But it seems, Provider is not playing well with Spring Framework

Whenever I try to execute `Provider` `get()` method, the Spring Autowired Environment Bean is not injected

I suspect that when calling `get()`, we're getting JSR330 managed Bean and not Spring Managed Bean

Look at the Snippets

**BeanClass.java**

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class BeanClass implements Iface {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Override
    public void doit() {
        System.out.println("hoo hoo "+env.getProperty("propkey"));
    }
}
```

**Classy.java**

```
@Component
public class Classy {
    @Autowired
    private Provider<Iface> ifaceProvider;
    public void doit_general() {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            Iface if = ifaceProvider.get();
            if.doit();
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this, I get an Error specifying that "environment" bean is not available

Or should I use @Inject in-place of @Autowired? I'm not so sure...

Any Spring Sensei who can clarify this and provide a Solution?

**Stacktrace:**

```
StackTrace: ----
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DBXMLToTransImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dbconn'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oracleDBConnection': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'environment' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getObject(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$Jsr330DependencyProvider.get(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at tpt.process.routers.ADImportOperationRouter.route(ADImportOperationRouter.java:110)
    at tpt.process.routers.ADImportOperationRouter.run(ADImportOperationRouter.java:159)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oracleDBConnection': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'environment' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'environment' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ShortcutDependencyDescriptor.resolveShortcut(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:740)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolvedCachedArgument(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:548)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.access$200(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:577)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    ... 25 more
```

**Update:**

This is strange... When I created a dummy code and replicated the same, The Environment got injected properly in the `@Autowired` field...

Refer: [Threaded Beans and Autowiring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45076679/threaded-beans-doesnt-get-environment-autowired-to-them-in-spring-when-using-j) for more Details

Comment: It doesn't matter what you're using `@Autowired` or `@Inject`, they are equal.

Comment: Your code is correct. Which version of spring are you using?

Comment: @BohdanLevchenko, Spring Version `4.3.9.RELEASE` and JSR330 `javax.inject version 1`

Comment: Well, it should work fine, please add a stacktrace to your question

Comment: @BohdanLevchenko, Included the Stack Trace... When I created a dummy code to check the Environment Being Autowired, it worked... but in the main code, i got the error... May be if we extend an abstract class, Environment is not injected? I'll check the dummy code with extending Abstract class

Comment: Looks very strange, can you try defining environment bean manually like: `@Bean Environment environment(ApplicationContext context) { return context.getEnvironment();}` ?

Comment: @BohdanLevchenko, When I include `@Bean
 public Environment environment(ApplicationContext context) {
  return context.getEnvironment();
 }` in the Configuration class, the environment is injected and it works fine... but isn't it bad to use Application Context inside the Classes other than the main method... Coz it's Inversion of Inversion of Control...

Comment: Is it because of the `@Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
  return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }` line in configuration class that the Environment is not injected? perhaps... Just a thought

Comment: Using `ApplicationContext` or any spring specific classes in **configurations** is perfectly normal since configurations are already coupled to spring. But anyway try to locate the bean which prevents normal injection of `Environment`

Comment: @BohdanLevchenko, I just found it... A bug in Spring Framework(may be I'm exaggerating)... When we use a thread, the Application context closes the resources and when the thread tries to access the Environment resource(using provider), it ends up with nothing...

Comment: Well, it happens) Feel free to open a jira issue if you think it is a bug, it might help somebody in the future :)